# I need to convert my UIImagePickerController code from Objective-C to Swift syntax

Tags: ios, swift, camera, uiimagepickercontroller, video-capture

All of my apps were written in Objective-C and I would like to convert them to swift. I have gotten it all finished except the camera code is driving me insane, as all of the UIImagePickerController examples I find do not continue to explain the video camera and how to use the file that has been recorded.

[image: screenshot]
<sub>(source: [rink-tank.com](http://www.rink-tank.com/Sample_Images/SampleScreenshot.png))</sub>

I would like the user to be able to tap on a camera button, record a video, then when dismissing the camera view, have the video load into a container view with an AVPlayerViewController embedded in it so they can see the video paused before they decide to play it.

I have tried the following in Swift (Note I'm not quite sure how to handle the segue now to have the AVPlayerViewController play the file:

```
 @IBAction func openVideoCamera(_ sender: Any) {
        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera) {
            let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
            imagePicker.delegate = self
            imagePicker.sourceType = .camera
            imagePicker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeMovie as String]
            imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
            present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        func imagePickerController (_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
            let mediaType = info [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.mediaType] as AnyObject
            
            if mediaType as! String == kUTTypeMovie as String {
                let videoURL = info [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.mediaURL] as? URL
                print("VIDEO URL: \(videoURL!)")
                sourcepath = videoURL
         

            }
            dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
            if segue.identifier == "embedPlayerSegue" {
```

My former code was this in Objective-C

```
- (IBAction)useCamera:(id)sender
{
    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
        
    {
        UIImagePickerController *videoScreen = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        videoScreen.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        
        // Displays movie capture control
        videoScreen.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie, nil];
        
        videoScreen.allowsEditing = NO;
        videoScreen.delegate = self;
        
        [self presentViewController:videoScreen animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    else
    {
        //Step 1: Create a UIAlertController
        UIAlertController *myAlertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Uh Oh"
                                                                                   message: @"This device does not have a camera so this functionality won't work - sorry!"
                                                                            preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert                   ];
        
        //Step 2: Create a UIAlertAction that can be added to the alert
        UIAlertAction* ok = [UIAlertAction
                             actionWithTitle:@"OK"
                             style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                             handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                             {
                                 //Do some thing here, eg dismiss the alertwindow
                                 [myAlertController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                                 
                             }];
        
        //Step 3: Add the UIAlertAction ok that we just created to our AlertController
        [myAlertController addAction: ok];
        
        //Step 4: Present the alert to the user
        [self presentViewController:myAlertController animated:YES completion:nil];
        
    }
}

- (IBAction)chooseFromAlbum:(id)sender
{
    UIImagePickerController *mediaUI = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    mediaUI.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
    mediaUI.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (NSString *) kUTTypeMovie, nil];
    // Hides the controls for moving & scaling pictures, or for
    // trimming movies. To instead show the controls, use YES.
    mediaUI.allowsEditing = YES;
    mediaUI.delegate = self;
    // 3 - Display image picker
    
    [self presentViewController:mediaUI animated:YES completion:NULL];
    
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UIImagePickerControllerDelegate

-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    // 1 - Get media type
    NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
    // 2 - Dismiss image picker
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
    // Handle a movie capture
    if (CFStringCompare ((__bridge_retained CFStringRef)mediaType, kUTTypeMovie, 0) == kCFCompareEqualTo)
    {
        _videoURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
        
        ///Save Video - Works!
        /* UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum([_videoURL path], nil, nil, nil);*/
        _myURL = [info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL  ];
        
        _playerViewController.player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:_videoURL];
        
        [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
        
        
    }
}


-(void)image:(UIImage *)image
finishedSavingWithError:(NSError *)error
 contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo
{
    if (error) {
        UIAlertController * alert = [UIAlertController
                                     alertControllerWithTitle:@"Save Failed"
                                     message:@"Failed to save image"
                                     preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
        
        
        UIAlertAction* noButton = [UIAlertAction
                                   actionWithTitle:@"OK"
                                   style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                   handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                                       //Handle no, thanks button
                                   }];
        
        
        [alert addAction:noButton];
        
        [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];    }
}
-(void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (IBAction)cancelCamera:(id)sender
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}


- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showMovieSegue"])
    {
        _playerViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        _playerViewController.player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:_videoURL];
        
    }
    
}
```

I am currently stuck and I have SCOURED the net for answers, but as I said, all answers cover just the photo function and not the video camera. I feel like this is should be easier to do than it it, so I truly appreciate any help. I have tried to include the screenshot but I just can't get that to work here. The direct link is:

http://www.rink-tank.com/Sample_Images/SampleScreenshot

Answer (score 0):

ur code is done with swift try it out

```
@IBAction func useCamera(_ sender: Any) {
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera) {
        let videoScreen = UIImagePickerController()
        videoScreen.sourceType = .camera

        // Displays movie capture control
        videoScreen.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeMovie as String]

        videoScreen.allowsEditing = false
        videoScreen.delegate = self

        present(videoScreen, animated: true)
    } else {
        //Step 1: Create a UIAlertController
        let myAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Uh Oh", message: "This device does not have a camera so this functionality won't work - sorry!", preferredStyle: .alert)

        //Step 2: Create a UIAlertAction that can be added to the alert
        let ok = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { action in
                //Do some thing here, eg dismiss the alertwindow
                myAlertController.dismiss(animated: true)

            })

        //Step 3: Add the UIAlertAction ok that we just created to our AlertController
        myAlertController.addAction(ok)

        //Step 4: Present the alert to the user
        present(myAlertController, animated: true)
    }
}

@IBAction func choose(fromAlbum sender: Any) {
    let mediaUI = UIImagePickerController()
    mediaUI.sourceType = .savedPhotosAlbum
    mediaUI.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeMovie as String]
    // Hides the controls for moving & scaling pictures, or for
    // trimming movies. To instead show the controls, use YES.
    mediaUI.allowsEditing = true
    mediaUI.delegate = self
    // 3 - Display image picker

    present(mediaUI, animated: true)


}



// MARK: -
// MARK: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    // 1 - Get media type
    let mediaType = info[.mediaType] as? String
    // 2 - Dismiss image picker
    dismiss(animated: false)
    // Handle a movie capture
    if CFStringCompare(mediaType as CFString?, kUTTypeMovie, 0) == .compareEqualTo {
        videoURL = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.mediaURL]

        ///Save Video - Works!
        // UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum([_videoURL path], nil, nil, nil);
        myURL = info[.referenceURL]

        playerViewController.player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL)

        picker.dismiss(animated: true)
    }
}

func image(_ image: UIImage?, finishedSavingWithError error: Error?, contextInfo: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    if error != nil {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Save Failed", message: "Failed to save image", preferredStyle: .alert)


        let noButton = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { action in
                //Handle no, thanks button
            })


        alert.addAction(noButton)

        present(alert, animated: true)
    }
}

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    dismiss(animated: true)
}

@IBAction func cancelCamera(_ sender: Any) {
    dismiss(animated: true)
}

func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if (segue.identifier == "showMovieSegue") {
        playerViewController = segue.destination
        playerViewController.player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL)
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you @arunPrasath - can you tell me what declarations I need to make at the beginning of the file? Like I said I am new to swift to I'd like to compare to help me learn. In my original I had the following:

'''

Comment: Sorry I can't figure out how to post it in the comments with correct formatting. I am down to two errors now:

videoURL = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.mediaURL] error says CANNOT ASSIGN VALUE OF TYPE 'ANY?' TO TYPE 'URL?'

2nd error: myURL = info[.referenceURL] Error is Use of unresolved identifier 'myURL'

Comment: Let me know if I can DM you the entire file somehow to look at